# How can I show a message after uninstalling a WiX Burn bundle?

Tags: wix, burn

How can I add a message to the successfully uninstalled page of a [Burn bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/)?

I am using `HyperlinkSidebarLicense` of the WiX standard bootstrapper application and use a copy of the default theme (at `src\ext\BalExtension\wixstdba\Resources\HyperlinkSidebarTheme.xml`):

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
    LicenseUrl=""
    ThemeFile="Theme.xml"
    LocalizationFile="Theme.wxl" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

I then modified the `Success` page by adding a `Text`:

```
<Page Name="Success">
  ...
  <Text Name="SuccessUninstallMessage" X="185" Y="110" Width="-11" Height="40" 
        FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessMessage)</Text>  
  ...
</Page>
```

However the modified `Success` page is also shown during installation (in addition to uninstall), which I don't want.

*How can I show a message only during uninstall on the `Success` page?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported in WixStdBA in WiX v3.x. WixStdBA has code to show different messages based on the action and it only does that for the header text (SuccessHeader, SuccessInstallHeader, SuccessRepairHeader, and SuccessUninstallHeader).

In WiX v4.0 (not yet in beta), themes can conditionally control the text shown without requiring supporting code in WixStdBA:

```
<Label X="0" Y="250" Width="-0" Height="20" FontId="1" Center="yes">
    <Text Condition="WixBundleAction = 5">#(loc.SuccessInstallMessage)</Text>
    <Text Condition="WixBundleAction = 6">#(loc.SuccessInstallMessage)</Text>
    <Text Condition="WixBundleAction = 7">#(loc.SuccessRepairMessage)</Text>
    <Text Condition="WixBundleAction = 3">#(loc.SuccessUninstallMessage)</Text>
</Label>
```